# Terminal's font color changed after bash script executing

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I have such a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

temp=`inxi -xxx -w`
regex="(Conditions:(.+))(Wind:(.+))Humidity"
[[ $temp =~ $regex ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
```

And it works cool, except such a detail - font color has changed, and now whole text became blue. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To avoid blue output:**

```
#!/bin/bash

temp=$(inxi -xxx -w | sed -r 's/\x1B\[[0-9;]*[JKmsu]//g')
regex="(Conditions:(.+))(Wind:(.+))Humidity"
[[ $temp =~ $regex ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
```

Changes I've made:

- Backtick (`` ` ``) is deprecated. Use `$(command)` instead of `` `command` ``.
- You can remove the color codes from the output of `inxi` with the `sed` regex onto I pipe it.

---

**To use blue output correctly:**

```
#!/bin/bash

temp=$(inxi -xxx -w)
regex="(Conditions:(.+))(Wind:(.+))Humidity"
[[ $temp =~ $regex ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
printf "\e[0m" # Reset the color.
```

- Instead of `\e` you can use `\033` or `\x1b`. All are the same thing.
- Instead of `[0m` you can use `[39;49;00m`.
- Instead of `printf` you can use `echo -e`, but I don't recommend it.

**Further reading:** http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes

Comment: Thank you very much :) Actually, it would be nice to save blue color in output of script, but to forbid changing common font color in terminal. Is it possible?